# @foreach(var item in Model) is NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

[image]I am using ASP.NET Core MVC. I try to display text when I submit the form and get a reply.

I do manage to update the data to the database, but I want to display them on the browser.

When I try to do this I encounter a `NullReferenceException` error even though I have data in the database

This is my code - controller:

```
 public ActionResult CommentIndex()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult _CommentIndex(Comment comment, int id)
    {
        ModelState.Clear();
        _context.Add(comment);
        _context.Comments.Add(comment);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        List<Comment> commentList = _context.Comments.ToList();

        return PartialView(commentList);
    }
```

My partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<PetShop.Data.Models.Comment>

  <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
           
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            @if (Model != null || Model.Count() < 1)
            {
                using (Html.BeginForm("CommentIndex", "Category", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <p>@item.Content</p>
                      
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
               <p>No results found</p>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

My view:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form id="commentPartial">
                <label>Enter your comment</label>
                <input type="text" id="Content" name="Content" placeholder="Enter your comment" />
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post Comment</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div id="commentDisplay"></div>
</div>
```

ajax in view:

```
    @section scripts {
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#commentPartial').submit(function () {
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "/Category/CommentIndex",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#commentDisplay').html(result);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

My Model:

```
public class Comment
{
    public Comment() => Animal = new Animal();
    [Key]
    public int CommentId { get; set; }
    public int AnimalId { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AnimalId")]
    public virtual Animal Animal { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `"but I want to display them on the browser"` In browser where do you want to display? In pop up or on Label?

Comment: I want to write a comment and then below that see what I wrote on the label

Comment: Did you checked that your `@foreach(var item in Model)` model is getting value while you debug? Additinally share your `Comment model` details

Comment: i edit my post to share you my comment but i did debug and i dont know why do I get null , when I add to view list of comments @Md Farid Uddin Kiron

Comment: Got your issue, just need to `Index1` view to reproduce the issue. The reason for your error is while you are binding the `partial view` you are not initiating with value, so your `foreeach loop` is getting nothing to iterate. So you have to pass intial value from your `Index1` `Post` controller to it.

Comment: @Md Farid Uddin Kiron I understood you but how can I fix it?

Comment: Thank you very much I have not yet learned ajax but I will try to understand
@Md Farid Uddin Kiron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your expectations assuming you are looking for something like
below:

***Output***

[image]

***Controller Action For Initial Page***

```
 public ActionResult CommentIndex()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

***View For Display Initial Page***

```cs
@{
}
<div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <form id="commentPartial">
                    <label>Enter your comment</label>
                    <input type="text" id="Content" name="Content" placeholder="Enter your comment" />
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post Comment</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        @*This is where your comment partial view will appear appear when user hits submit on our form*@
        <div id="commentDisplay"></div>
    </div>




    @section scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //When the user hit the submit button we will post the form results to our partial view controller
            $('#commentPartial').submit(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "/Controller/_CommentIndex",
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function (result) {
                        //When then load our partial view into our containing div on the main page
                        $('#commentDisplay').html(result);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
    }
```

***Controller Action For Partial View***

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult _CommentIndex([Bind("Content,AnimalId")] Comment comment, int id)
{
    
    _context.Comments.Add(comment);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    List<Comment> commentList = _context.Comments.ToList();

    return PartialView(commentList);
}
```

**Note:** Feel free to implement your logic for `ModelState.IsValid` or any conditional you want according to your requirement.

***Model used in above controller***

```cs
public class Comment
    {
        public int CommentId { get; set; }
        public int AnimalId { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }
```

**Note:** I am using on `Content` property for testing the scenario, feel free to modify as per your need.

***Partial View***

```cs
@model IEnumerable<DotNetMVCWebApp.Models.Comment>

    <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
               
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                @if (Model != null || Model.Count() < 1)
                {
                    using (Html.BeginForm("CommentIndex", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
                    {
                        foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <p>@item.Content</p>
                          
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                   <p>No results found</p>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Note:** While you would be creating this `partial view` remember to add Comment And add `List` kind of partial view.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243808/discussion-on-answer-by-md-farid-uddin-kiron-foreachvar-item-in-model-is-null).